# How to maketable view loads old data with the new data after reload and hides old data after 25 seconds in ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a table view which loads data at a button click. Initially the table is loaded with data from the database.

When any other button is clicked the table is loaded with new data along with the old data. The old data gets disappeared after 10 seconds.

What is the issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: show you code for fetching new data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On basic information you placed, what i understand is :**

- Initially you are showing local data from database
- After that on button click i guess you are showing data from API or something like that

**If this is the case than:**

- It will take some time to load new data from server & than it will be shown to Tableview
- You need to show data Asynchronously, You need to use lazy loading technique

**Note:**

- If on button click, still you are showing data from local database, there might happen due to large data it will take time to load. Just put the progress indicator & use Lazy loading technique to load data

I hope this will help you.